# Returning the "search term" along with result - Elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

In the elasticsearch module I have built, is it possible to return the "input search term" in the search results ?

For example :

```
GET /signals/_search
{
"query": {
"match": {
   "focused_content": "stock"
}
}
}
```

This returns

```
{
"took": 2,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
  "total": 1,
  "max_score": 0.057534903,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "signals",
        "_type": "signal",
        "_id": "13",
        "_score": 0.057534903,
        "_source": {
           "username": "abc@abc.com",
           "tags": [
              "News"
           ],
           "content_url": "http://www.wallstreetscope.com/morning-stock-highlights-western-digital-corporation-wdc-fibria-celulose-sa-fbr-ametek-inc-ame-cott-corporation-cot-graftech-international-ltd-gti/25375462/",
           "source": null,
           "focused_content": "Morning Stock Highlights: Western Digital Corporation (WDC), Fibria Celulose SA (FBR), Ametek Inc. (AME), Cott Corporation (COT), GrafTech International Ltd. (GTI) - WallStreet Scope",
           "time_stamp": "2015-08-12"
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to have the input search term "stock" along with each of the results (like an additional JSON Key along with "content_url","source","focused_content","time_stamp") to identify which search term had brought that result ?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of, would be using [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-request-highlighting.html)  feature. So it would bring back additional key `_highlight`and it would highlight things, that matched.

It won't bring exact matching terms, tho. You'd have to deal with them in your application. You could use pre/post tags functionality to wrap them up somehow specially, so your app could recognize that it was a match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use highlights on all fields, like @Evaldas suggested. This will return the result along with the value in the field which matched, surrounded by customisable tags (default is `<em>`).

```
GET /signals/_search
{
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
    "username": {},
    "tags": {},
    "source": {},
    "focused_content": {},
    "time_stamp": {}
  }
},
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "focused_content": "stock"
    }
  }
}
```